# mongodb - how to empty out a hash

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongodb. I have the following document/json with these (4) fields.

```
"ready_state" : {
    "user" : "abcd@abc.com",
    "state" : "green",
    "audit_date" : ISODate("2016-04-03T14:27:11.494Z"),
    "profile" : "tst"
},
```

How do I empty out this hash? Output expected would be:

```
"ready_state" : {
},
```

Can someone provide example on how to do so using `pull` and `set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply replace the value of `ready_state` with the new value. Using `$set` you can do something like this:

```
db.collection.update(query, { $set: { ready_state: {} });
```

Comment: Got it. That works. Can you also use `pull` to pull off these values?

Comment: @noober $pull only operates on named properties so you would have to list which properties to remove, but I'm  not sure of the correct syntax. It is easy to test with a mongo shell and the documentation https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/